# Javascript code help - Wrong return

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

So I'm working on this script. When I'm done with it, it should be used for making 2-and-2 groups. But anyway; The 'input' array in the start of the script, will get 22 different inputs from my HTML file. As a standard, I gave them the values 1-22. The thing is my two blocks '1st number' and '2nd number' doesn't work very well: they don't return the right numbers. Cause I want every elev[x] to be used once! Not 2 times, not 0 times, once! And the blocks returns like some of them twice and some of them isn't even used. So how can I fix this?

```
    function Calculate(){
    var elev = [];
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName("txt");
    for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    elev[i] = {
        "Value": inputs[i].value,
        "Used": false
    };
}

    function shuffle(elev){
    var len = elev.length;
    for(i=1; i<len; i++){
        j = ~~(Math.random()*(i+1)); 
        var temp = elev[i];
        arr[i] = elev[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    for(var v=0; v<1; v++) {
        shuffle(elev);
        document.write(elev + '<br/>\n');
    }}
```

Yes, I'm still new at programming and I just wanna learn what I can learn.

**Problem solved by doing the Fisher-Yates shuffle.**

Comment: `elev[r] = elev[a];
                    elev[a] = elev[r];` will not swap two elements. First, it assigns `elev[a]` to `elev[r]` (losing the value of `elev[r]`), then assigns the same value back to `elev[a]`.

Comment: Why do you have a loop around `shuffle`? I used a loop to generate multiple shuffles (to prove it's random), but I was under the impression you only needed one.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Use DOM manipulation or at least `document.body.innerHTML +=`

Comment: Also, objects don't convert to string exactly well unless you implement `toString`, so printing an array of objects won't do any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of shuffling an array and iterating over it is correct, however, sorting by a coin-flipping comparator (a common mis-implementation; suggested by the other answer) is *not* the correct way to shuffle an array; it produces very skewed results and is not even guaranteed to finish.

Unless you're willing to fetch underscore.js (`arr = _.shuffle(arr)`), It is recommended to use the Fisher-Yates shuffle:

```
function shuffle(arr){
  var len = arr.length;
  for(var i=1; i<len; i++){
    var j = ~~(Math.random()*(i+1)); // ~~ = cast to integer
    var temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
  }
}

...

shuffle(elev);
for(var i=0; i<elev.length; i++){
  //do something with elev[i]
  console.log(elev[i].Value);
}
```

also, note that object fields should be lowercase, not uppercase (`value', not 'Value'). Also, the`Used` field should not be neccessary since you now iterate in order. Also, any chance you could use an array of Values? They seem to be the only field in your objects.

Also, **Don't use document.write()**. It doesn't work as expected when used after the page load. If you want to append something to the document, you hate jQuery and other frameworks and you don't want to go the long way of creating and composing DOM nodes,  `document.body.innerHTML +=` is still better than `document.write()` (but still consider appending `DocumentFragment`s instead').

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/2GSDd/1/

Comment: I'm just confused about a few things. What is temp (please drop a link if, there isn't a short answer), and what about the 'i' and 'j' index's? And can I just copy/paste the script above?

Comment: @Jan You forgot to `var` your `i` and `j` and the shuffle is normally done downwards rather than upwards but seems to work fine. I very rarely see other people use `~~` to cast to integer!

Comment: @PaulS. Counting upwards is allowed, and it's called the inside-out method. It's used if you want to initialise the array while shuffling at the same time. Thanks for the `var`s.

Comment: @user1994248 Because as soon as you do `x = y` the previous value of `x` is overwritten, if you also wanted to do `y = x` to "swap" them, `x` is now `y`, so you're telling it `y = y`, which is pointless. Instead, you introduce a new variable to store `x` `temp`orarily. Now, `temp = x; x = y; y = temp;` and everything is as you intended.

Comment: @PaulS. Interestingly, `~~x` is slightly faster than `x|0` in chrome: http://jsperf.com/number-cast

Comment: @JanDvorak this is Number->Number, not Text->Number, so instead see [this perf](http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/33), where `~~x` is about the same or very slightly slower than `|0` or `>>0` in most versions.

Comment: @user1994248 code on stack overflow is licenced under Creative Commons With Attribution, meaning you are free to use the code if you link to this answer from nearby. It will work in every browser as well.

Comment: @PaulS, I understand. Again, I'm still new and wanna hear if anyone can do the shuffle function for me. I tried just to copy/paste it, but it just returned '[object Object],[object Object]' and so on.

Comment: @user1994248 what did you try to copy/paste? If you try to shuffle an array of objects, it will be an array of objects after the shuffle.

Comment: @JanDvorak I tried to copypaste the whole code above and used it for my code (1st post - without the two blocks '1st number' and '2nd number')

Comment: @user1994248 what do you pass to the function? Objects in, objects out.

Comment: @user1994248 see my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/2GSDd/1/) to see how to use the function.

Comment: @JanDvorak that really helped a lot! I'm gonna try this out.

Comment: I updated it (first post) but what's wrong? I think it should be correct.

Comment: @user1994248 updated but also see my comments under the question.

Comment: Thank you all! It's working, and I can thank all of you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting random numbers once, and then processing them if they haven't already been used.

I would suggest shuffling the array (`elev.sort(function() {return Math.random()-0.5})`) and then just iterating through the result without further random numbers.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5].sort(Math.random)` gives `[5,4,3,2,1]` almost exactly 100% of the time.. not very random.

Comment: Your shuffling algorithm is bad, even if the comparator worked as you expect.

Comment: Oh, that sounds easy. Will try to do that, and see if it works. When I'm done with that will I update the post. **EDIT:** So, should I use it or not?

Comment: @Kolink still a bad way to shuffle an array.

Comment: @JanDvorak What would you suggest?

Comment: @Kolink the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle): `for(i in 0..len-1) swap(arr, i, random(0..i))`

Comment: @user1994248 this is a bad way to shuffle an array. See my previous comment on the proper way.

Comment: I don't think I get it. Could you please make an answer as is a little more detailed?

Comment: @JanDvorak good job noticing that. I can't edit so here it is again (and I'll delete prev. to save people copying in error) `function shuffleArray(a) {var i = a.length, t, j; while (--i) t = a[i], a[i] = a[j = ~~(Math.random() * (i+1))], a[j] = t;}`

Comment: @PaulS. It seems fine now. I still don't like the assignment inside square brackets.