# Append two images randomly from array into 'li's with javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I am basically trying to dynamically add an Array of images randomly into their own li elements, which is working fine, but what I really want to do now is append a second image per list element. I'm not sure how this would work. Here's my working randomiser script which shuffles the array order:

```
var imgs = ['img-1.jpg','img-2.jpg','img-3.jpg','img-4.jpg','img-5.jpg','img-6.jpg'];

var i = imgs.length, j, tempi, tempj;
while (i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    tempi = imgs[i];
    tempj = imgs[j];
    imgs[i] = tempj;
    imgs[j] = tempi;

    var img = imgs[i];
    var folder = 'img/';

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'phototickr';
    document.getElementById('stream').appendChild(li);

    var tickr = document.createElement('img');
    tickr.src = folder + img;
    tickr.alt = '';

    li.appendChild(tickr);
}
```

The final markup I want is this:

```
<ul id="stream">
<li><img src="img-1.jpg"><img src="img-2.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img-3.jpg"><img src="img-4.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img-5.jpg"><img src="img-6.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Not sure how to get my head around it, or if there is a clean solution, much appreciated any help. And no, I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: Are both of these images going to be from the same list? Or will you have a separate list to pull from?

Comment: @THEtheChad - I was hoping to specify them all from the same array, so if I had 6 images, it would split them evenly among 3 list elements - if that makes sense. I know it could be done easily with two arrays of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shuffle the array in advance and then the task becomes much clearer, but you need to make an allowance for if you have an odd number of images.

```
var imgs = ['img-1.jpg','img-2.jpg','img-3.jpg','img-4.jpg','img-5.jpg','img-6.jpg'];

function shuffleArray(a) { // Fisher-Yates shuffle
    var i = a.length, t, j;
    while (--i) t = a[i], a[i] = a[j = ~~(Math.random() * (i+1))], a[j] = t;
}
shuffleArray(imgs);

var i = imgs.length, stream, li, img1, img2;
stream = document.getElementById('stream');
while ((i = i - 2) >= 0) {
    // <li>
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'phototickr';
    // <img>
    img1 = document.createElement('img');
    img1.src = 'img/' + imgs[i];
    img1.alt = '';
    img2 = document.createElement('img');
    img2.src = 'img/' + imgs[i + 1];
    img2.alt = '';
    // append
    li.appendChild(img1);
    li.appendChild(img2);
    stream.appendChild(li);
}
if (i === -1) { // odd number of images
    // <li>
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'phototickr';
    // <img>
    img1 = document.createElement('img');
    img1.src = 'img/' + imgs[0];
    img1.alt = '';
    // append
    li.appendChild(img1);
    stream.appendChild(li);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChvMU/) (with broken images)

Comment: You could even use `while((i -= 2) >= 0)`, although at this point I'd go with a more readable `for(int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i += 2)` loop. (I have to admit though, that is one amazingly compressed in-place Fisher-Yates implementation you have there!)

Comment: Thanks Paul, this looks really good. I accepted the above answer before you posted this, so my apologies, but in terms of performance, is the above (or yours) the better solution, as they both definitely work very well, thanks for putting the time into helping me.

Comment: @Todd at a quick glance, they look about equal with two differences; 1. THEtheChad's document fragment will save you a few redraws which might matter if you're doing hundreds of iterations (so his is most likely faster by a few nanoseconds), but 2. he doesn't put every image in from an array of odd length.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Yes, those may be more readable. I wrote that Fisher-Yates a few days ago [as a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487040/javascript-code-help-wrong-return/14487124#comment20188101_14487124) (hence the compression) and am happy I finally got to use it in an answer!

Comment: Ah, superb Paul! I just dropped the img-6.jpg and you're right, yours is the better as it ads a new list element for the loner-image. Well done on using your Fisher-yates haha! :) thanks again, mega appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I revised your algorithm a bit so that you're not constantly appending items to the DOM (as that lowers performance). I'm adding images to the li and then adding the li to a document fragment. I'm not 100% sure what your goal is but I think this gets you on the right track.

```
var imgs = [
  'img-1.jpg',
  'img-2.jpg',
  'img-3.jpg',
  'img-4.jpg',
  'img-5.jpg',
  'img-6.jpg'
];

function randomize(list){
  var i = list.length, j, tempi, tempj;
  if(i == 0) return false;
  while(--i){
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    tempi = list[i];
    tempj = list[j];
    list[i] = tempj;
    list[j] = tempi;
  }
}

function buildList(){
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var folder   = 'img/';

  randomize(imgs);
  var l = imgs.length;
  while(l > 1){
    var img1 = imgs[--l];
    var img2 = imgs[--l];

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'phototickr';

    var tickr1 = document.createElement('img');
    tickr1.src = folder + img1;
    tickr1.alt = '';

    var tickr2 = document.createElement('img');
    tickr2.src = folder + img2;
    tickr2.alt = '';

    li.appendChild(tickr1);
    li.appendChild(tickr2);
    fragment.appendChild(li);
  }

  document.getElementById('stream').appendChild(fragment);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason though it's not showing any images for me. Any ideas to the cause? I can't see that anything is wrong.

Comment: Ahh, had to call the buildList(); function, that'd be why :) thanks very much!