# Adding a picture button in js

Tags: javascript, html, button, imagebutton

I have my code working tho what i would like it's to customize the text link so it should be a picture.

Example the "View" text link will be /pics/icon.png  and "Edit", /pics/icon2.png

Here it's my code:

```
    var $container = $( "#daif_results" );
            $container.empty();
            $.each( items, function() {
                var str = '<li>' + this.label + ' - <a href="' + daif_consts.home_url + '?p=' + this.value + 
                          '">View</a>  - <a href="' + daif_consts.admin_url + 'post.php?post=' + this.value + '&amp;action=edit">Edit</a></li>';
                $container.append( str );
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't run your code, but I believe you are trying to add images to one of your lists. I think you could use CSS to achieve that, like [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_list-style-image).

I also found a javascript example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552922/append-two-images-randomly-from-array-into-lis-with-javascript).

I think you could create an image element:

```
img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "http://sourcetoimage";
```

And then append it to your list:

```
li.appendChild(img);
```

Here's a [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gr5LL23d/).